# Using an order by case in a sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

Each schedule has many ramps, and each ramp has an `end_date`.

I need to list all my ramps, along with an extra field that contains the id of the ramp with the latest end date for that schedule. I also need to be able to use this extra field in my `WHERE` clause.

This is typically a case for a sub-query using the `MAX` function, except for one problem: the ramp's `end_date` field can be null, indicating the ramp is current. Thus, `SELECT MAX(end_date)` doesn't work, since `null` values are 'smaller' than non-null values.

So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
SELECT r1.*,
    (SELECT r2.id
    FROM ramp as r2
    WHERE schedule_id = r.schedule_id
    ORDER BY IF(end_dte is NULL, '9999-99-99', end_dte) DESC
    LIMIT 1) as latestId
FROM ramp as r1
```

This produces this table, which is exactly what I want:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
| id    | schedule_id | suppr_flag | comment         | months | start_dte  | end_dte    | latestId |
+-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
|    16 |           7 | NULL       | NULL            |   NULL | 2008-06-23 | NULL       |       16 |
|    15 |           6 | NULL       | NULL            |   NULL | 2007-05-01 | 2007-12-31 |       15 |
|    13 |           5 | NULL       | 1-15 deals      |   NULL | 2004-08-11 | NULL       |       13 |
|    11 |           4 | NULL       | NULL            |   NULL | 2005-08-11 | NULL       |       11 |
|    12 |           4 | NULL       | NULL            |     12 | 2004-08-11 | 2005-08-10 |       11 |
|    17 |          13 | NULL       | NULL            |      6 | 2009-03-05 | 2009-09-04 |       19 |
|    18 |          13 | NULL       | NULL            |      6 | 2009-09-05 | 2010-03-04 |       19 |
|    19 |          13 | NULL       | NULL            |   NULL | 2010-03-05 | NULL       |       19 |
|    20 |          14 | NULL       | NULL            |     12 | 2001-06-18 | 2008-06-17 |       20 |
```

except I cannot use `latestId` in a WHERE clause (it's an unknown column).

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to repeat the whole query on the ORDER BY clause, because an alias is not seen there, but I don't like much how the query will look:

```
SELECT r1.*,
    (SELECT r2.id
    FROM ramp as r2
    WHERE schedule_id = r1.schedule_id
    ORDER BY IF(end_dte is NULL, '9999-99-99', end_dte) DESC
    LIMIT 1) as latestId
FROM ramp as r1
ORDER BY
    (SELECT r2.id
    FROM ramp as r2
    WHERE schedule_id = r1.schedule_id
    ORDER BY IF(end_dte is NULL, '9999-99-99', end_dte) DESC
    LIMIT 1);
```

Or you can SELECT from your original query, and order the result:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (
  SELECT r1.*,
      (SELECT r2.id
      FROM ramp as r2
      WHERE schedule_id = r1.schedule_id
      ORDER BY IF(end_dte is NULL, '9999-99-99', end_dte) DESC
      LIMIT 1) as latestId
  FROM ramp as r1
) s
ORDER BY s.latestId
```

But if I understand your logic correcty, you could use this query to get the maximum `end_dte` for every `schedule_id`:

```
SELECT schedule_id, MAX(COALESCE(end_dte, '9999-12-31')) max_dte
FROM ramp
GROUP BY schedule_id;
```

Then you can JOIN this query with ramp again to get the ID associated to the maximum `end_dte`. On the ON clause you will neet to use COALESCE again:

```
SELECT r1.schedule_id, r2.id as latestId
FROM (
  SELECT schedule_id, MAX(COALESCE(end_dte, '9999-12-31')) max_dte
  FROM ramp
  GROUP BY schedule_id) r1 INNER JOIN
  ramp r2
  ON r1.max_dte = COALESCE(r2.end_dte, '9999-12-31')
     AND r1.schedule_id = r2.schedule_id
```

And then you can join this again to get the result you need:

```
SELECT ramp.*, m.latestId
FROM
  ramp INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r1.schedule_id, r2.id as latestId
    FROM (
      SELECT schedule_id, MAX(COALESCE(end_dte, '9999-12-31')) max_dte
      FROM ramp
      GROUP BY schedule_id) r1 INNER JOIN
      ramp r2
      ON r1.max_dte = COALESCE(r2.end_dte, '9999-12-31')
         AND r1.schedule_id = r2.schedule_id
      ) m ON ramp.schedule_id = m.schedule_id
ORDER BY
  latestId
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4676/1). Notice that I am using '9999-12-31' and not '9999-99-99', the first one is a valid date, the second not.

**Edit**

If you also wish to consider the fact that more than one `schedule_id` shares the same maximum date, and you just need the latest (maximum) ID in this case, you could use a GROUP BY query, and a MAX aggregated function:

```
SELECT r1.schedule_id, MAX(r2.id) as latestId
FROM (
  SELECT schedule_id, MAX(COALESCE(end_dte, '9999-12-31')) max_dte
  FROM ramp
  GROUP BY schedule_id) r1 INNER JOIN
  ramp r2
  ON r1.max_dte = COALESCE(r2.end_dte, '9999-12-31')
     AND r1.schedule_id = r2.schedule_id
GROUP BY
  r1.schedule_id
```

and you use this updated version in your main query.

Comment: Really wonderful. I didn't know you could do nested inner joins - I tried nested sub-queries but it either crashed or was impossible.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting two rows with different latestId values. I am doing some other joins. Any thoughts off the top of your head?

Comment: @SamSelikoff i think there might be more than one row with the same maximum `end_dte` for the same `schedule_id` ... if this is the problem, do you just want the maximum ID?

Comment: Ah yes I see. It's a data integrity problem (which is good, it's pointing out mistakes). In case I did just want the maximum ID, what would I do? Thanks btw, you rock.

Comment: @SamSelikoff thanks :) you could use a GROUP BY with a MAX aggregate function, i updated my answer.. i also added one more query at the beginnig, it's just a different idea... i hope the final query is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you could use TWO columns in your order... first for non-null indication flag, then by the date.  Change what you had of...

```
ORDER BY IF(end_dte is NULL, '9999-99-99', end_dte) DESC
```

to

```
ORDER BY
   IF( end_dte is null, 1, 2 ),
   end_dte DESC
```

This way, it pushes all "NULL" end dates to the top of the list (via IF() value would be 1 vs 2 for anything else that HAD a date),  THEN, by the date descending